# Writing data to S3 through Spark Data Frame and in scale - s3 connectivity issue and caused by s3 503 slow down error

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql, amazon-emr

We are trying to read and write the data to S3 in spark using AWS EMR clusters. And during this process, while we were scaling the execution, we ended up with some issues. When we try to process the same job for one-quarter of data we are not noticing this issue, but when we scale it to run multiple quarters of data in parallel, randomly for one/more quarters of data, we started seeing the spark jobs failing while writing the data to S3. Then we went down further to understand the issue in deeper, that is when we realized that spark is throwing the issue while it is writing the data to S3 and that is caused by S3 503 Slow down the error.

The slow down error will come only when we exceeded the S3 TPS of a given path. And the suggestion from S3 is to add random hash values to s3 path while writing. We tried this using partition by, but we come to know that some hash values(xy, 2 digit hash values) only will perform better. So does anyone come across the similar issue, and if so may I know how you had overcome this issue?

Looking forward!

Krish

Answer (score 0):

S3 client should be throttling back on the errors; surprised the EMR one wasn't as the AWS SDK everyone uses does recognise a 503 and will backoff and retry.

There'll probably be a config option to set it (for S3a://, its `fs.s3a.attempts.maximum`)

If you are using the EMR s3:// connector, you'll have to look for their option

Comment: As reading and writing to S3 started giving us various issues, we decided to write the spark output to hdfs and then move that data to s3 using s3-dist-cp. Even that is also giving the same issue. We had a lengthy discussion aws team and final conclusion that we hear from them was the s3 path needs to be changed. Like s3://bucketname/<hash>/prefix2/prefix3/.... Here the hash should be 2 chars & different for every day like a0,be,hd,ff,ba,etc... This way the load will get distributed to various paths and the slow down error will not come. We need to check if the bove property will help or not.

Comment: distcp needs to be better about shuffling its filenames before upload; see https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/cloud-integration/blob/master/spark-cloud-integration/src/main/scala/com/hortonworks/spark/cloud/applications/CloudCp.scala

Comment: Sure will check this.